# Highcharts translate drilldown

Tags: angular, highcharts

How could we translate name of drilldown series ? Only for drilldown, not for series lvl1, but for lvl2 and higher.

Code source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-kcavjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I tried to change it's name like in series case, but i can't get value from drilldown series, only for lvl1 series.
Notes: I'm using Angular.

Comment: can you provide code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-kcavjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @DEV, sorry. Here i want to translate from 777 / 888/ 999 to any values.

Comment: Hi @Tudor123, Please describe more precisely what you want to achieve. What do you exactly want to translate?

Comment: @ppotaczek, i want to translate from 777 / 888/ 999 from code source (after drilldown), to any values, depends by language. For example, 777 to Stack, 888 to Macbook. But only for drilldown series. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! Are you using some package for translations in your project?

Comment: @ppotaczek, jhitranslate, but it's ok if i would check it manually. There will be maximum 2 fields so we can do it with something like if  == "dada" {replace}.